# Получить путь директории Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

подскажите пожалуйста, может кто знает. 
Можно ли как-то в java получить корневой путь Томката?

Пример, у меня сейчас файлик лежит тут C:\OAPI\tomcat8\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\save\saveDistanceMap.ser и путь задан жестко в java коде.

Но я запускаю приложение на другой машине и путь другой, то естественно, он не видит данный файл.

Могу я при помощи каких-то инструментов получать путь при запуске приложения и уже просто в коде к переменной подставлять имя файла?

На формах почитал, не нашел ничего дельного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Когда вы устанавливаете томкат, то обычно выставляете системную переменную, которая указывает путь до него. Обычно переменную называют "$CATALINA_HOME". В жава коде можно получить значение любой системной переменной :

```
 String tomcatHome =  System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, у меня она оказалась не выставлена, из-за этого не мог ее увидеть.